# Open cart installation on Godaddy

Tags: opencart

I have shared hosting on my Godaddy with the basic (/.)

I have made a folder domains in shared hosting and made other websites in it e.g. /abc.com/shop/

Getting 500(Internal Server error)

Can anyone guide me to resolve the problem?

Thanks,
Ananta

Comment: please share your domain url  and ftp. i will fix it.

Comment: Thanks @haninder Singh Everything is fixed now. Apart from this, still I am not able to access my admin folder on server. Do you have any idea??

Comment: Could you pl share your email ID?

Comment: my skype id : harryr891